# Where is the AutheticationService class in Primavera 8 Web Service

Tags: c#, web-services, primavera

We are about to update our Primavera system from 6.x to 8.2. We have som applications that uses the webservice but having some problems.

In Primavera 6 we used Primaveras version of the DLL helper called: p6WSStubs.dll

In the newer versions they have a guide that explains how to create this file witch we have done.

However the classes and methods in the 2 files are not completely identical.

We uses Visual studio.

In the old Version we Could create an instance of a class called Authetication service like this:

Primavera.Ws.P6.Authentication.AuthenticationService auth = new Primavera.Ws.P6.Authentication.AuthenticationService();

in the new version we have created the Namespace Primavera.Ws.P6.Authentication like descriped in the guide but I only have the Classes and methods shown here:

[image]

Does anyone have any experience with the differences in webservice in the 2 version?

Comment: could you please post your binding's security settings? I am not able to get it right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can instantiate the `AuthenticationServicePortTypeClient` and use it as you used the service. Assuming you might be using C# 4.0 with VS 2010, that uses WCF to connect with SOAP based services and the way you interact is a little different than Microsoft WSE in .net 2.0.